# Batch file stuck depending on .... ¿¿¿¿folder?

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file to create a power plan. The final intention is to include it in a setup. But when I run the setup the batch file stays stuck (the setup bat file has no Pauses). After a lot of changes and reading, I decided to start from the beginning again, and I dicovered that the same batch file works depending on the folder (there are no relative paths). These are the facts

I'm running Windows 10 Pro

File 1: C:\Users\idoblas\Desktop\powerCFG\original\POWERCFG_ES.BAT
File 2: C:\Users\idoblas\Desktop\powerCFG\POWERCFG_ES.BAT

These are my tests:

- File 2 is a copy of file 1. Both have the same encoding, file size .... I
  have compared then using beyond compare and winmerge
- If I doubleclick file 1 it works perfectly (it will return an error
  asking for admin permissions) and if I run it as administrator it
  works also fine
- If I doubleclick file 2 it gets stuck @line 6 before the pause but it works fine when executed as administrator, this is the last line executed:

```
FOR /F "tokens=6" %%G IN ('powercfg /getactivescheme') DO set activeschemeGUID=%%G
```

- I've changed the permissions for file 2, giving everyone full control to file with no changes
- Tried in other folders and works like file 1, the problem is that in my setup the behavior is like in file 2
- If I run cmd.exe /k C:\Users\idoblas\Desktop\powerCFG\powercfg_es.bat from cmd shell it works, but from cmd window if I execute the batch file it gets also stuck

Here you are the code:

```
REM @echo off
SETLOCAL

REM Get GUID of current power scheme
REM tokens = 6 for spanish OS, tokens = 4 fo english OS
FOR /F "tokens=6" %%G IN ('powercfg /getactivescheme') DO set activeschemeGUID=%%G
PAUSE

REM Custom power scheme name
set custom_name=Evolv_power_plan
PAUSE

REM Check if it already exists and if it exists, get its GUID

FOR /F "tokens=6" %%G IN ('powercfg -list ^| find "%custom_name%"') DO (
    REM custom power scheme with that name already exists
    set custom_GUID=%%G
    goto :SetCustomActive
)
PAUSE

REM Here we're sure it doesn't exist: copy current active scheme and get GUID of that copy
FOR /F "tokens=6" %%G IN ('powercfg -DUPLICATESCHEME %activeschemeGUID%') DO set custom_GUID=%%G
PAUSE

REM change the name of the new scheme (the copy) to the custom name
powercfg -CHANGENAME %custom_GUID% %custom_name%
PAUSE

:SetCustomActive
powercfg -SETACTIVE %custom_GUID%
set activeschemeGUID=%custom_GUID%
PAUSE

REM Power settings allways ON
POWERCFG /CHANGE monitor-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /CHANGE monitor-timeout-dc 0

PAUSE

POWERCFG /CHANGE disk-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /CHANGE disk-timeout-dc 0

PAUSE

POWERCFG /CHANGE standby-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /CHANGE standby-timeout-dc 0

PAUSE

POWERCFG /CHANGE hibernate-timeout-ac 0
POWERCFG /CHANGE hibernate-timeout-dc 0

PAUSE

REM vISUALIZAR FAST STARTUP - HIBERNAR
powercfg /hibernate on

PAUSE

REM boton de power, QUE APAGUE
powercfg -setacvalueindex %activeschemeGUID% SUB_BUTTONS UIBUTTON_ACTION 2
powercfg -setdcvalueindex %activeschemeGUID% SUB_BUTTONS UIBUTTON_ACTION 2
powercfg -setacvalueindex %activeschemeGUID% SUB_BUTTONS PBUTTONACTION 000 
powercfg -setdcvalueindex %activeschemeGUID% SUB_BUTTONS PBUTTONACTION 000 

PAUSE

rem mantener usb
powercfg -setacvalueindex %activeschemeGUID% 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 0
powercfg -setdcvalueindex %activeschemeGUID% 2a737441-1930-4402-8d77-b2bebba308a3 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226 0

PAUSE
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: For batch-file 2, is it the only file in the batch file's directory? There isn't possibly another file named `powercfg` in that folder by chance?

Comment: You cannot create a batch file with the same name as a system executable. rename `powercfg.bat` to `powerconfig.bat` or something similar that does not exist already as an executable. `cmd` will look for the file in the current working directory before it looks at the environment paths. In this case it finds the `powercfg.bat` local and will not execute the `powercfg.exe` which is located in `C:\Windows\System32` alternatively, but not recommended use full path in your script. i.e `FOR /F "tokens=6" %%G IN ('C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe /getactivescheme') DO set activeschemeGUID=%%G`

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
@Squashman That was the problem! Thankyou very much!!!

Comment: @Gerhard Thanks, I will change file names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is provided by @Squashman

The problem was that in the same folder I had another batch file names powercfg.bat, so this loop

```
FOR /F "tokens=6" %%G IN ('powercfg -list ^| find "%custom_name%"') DO (
REM custom power scheme with that name already exists
set custom_GUID=%%G
goto :SetCustomActive
```

wasn't running system's powercfg.exe . When executed as administrator it's executed from admin's default folder so there was not powercfg.bat and it was correctly executed